# Convert "TRUE" to 1 in powershell variable

Tags: powershell

I am reading a cell from Excel which contains `TRUE` or `FALSE`. After reading it I need to insert the value in a table in SQL Server with datatype `bit`.

I get the value in the cell with this line of code:

```
   $myvariable =  $WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item($ExcelRowToRead, 10).Text
```

Is there a way to convert `TRUE` or `FALSE` to `1`or `0` without  writing an if statement?  I need `$myvariable` to become a 1/0 value..

Comment: Have you tried `[int][bool]$myvariable =  $WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item($ExcelRowToRead, 10).Text`?

Comment: What about [`$WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item($ExcelRowToRead, 10).Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the string value to `[bool]` with `bool.Parse`, then convert to `[int]`:

```
$myvariable = "TRUE"
$bit = [int][bool]::Parse($myvariable)
```

After which:

```
PS ~> $bit
1
```

Comment: Thanks! So this style with square brackets an double colon; what is it called?

Comment: `[Type]::Method` is a static method call, the `[int]` is a type-cast or conversion.

Comment: Lasse is spot on! `[bool]::Parse` <- means "invoke member 'Parse' on type 'bool'"